# Set AppBarLayout size Programmatically on Android

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

My `AppBarLayout` hold a `Toolbar` and `TabLayout`.  When view is anchored, height is set to 0 `setLayoutParams(0)`.  On another state, the view is collapsed, I need to restore appbar height. I tried `setLayoutParams(heightDp)` where

```
float heightDp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 6;
```

but the height is not accurate.

```
private void setLayoutParams(int paramsHeight) {
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lsp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    lsp.height = paramsHeight;
    mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lsp);
}
```

How can I determine exact `AppBar` height programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should get it from default resources with TypedArray:

```
int mActionBarSize;
TypedArray attrs= getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
mActionBarSize = (int) attrs.getDimension(0, 0);
```

You must recycle TypedArray

```
attrs.recycle();
```

This way you will get the value according to your screen.